# doGet(e) for display cell in Spreadsheet not it works

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function doGet(e) {
  var rngA1=e.parameter.range;
  Logger.log(rngA1);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ztil0F4Eo_MTf6g...");
  var content='\n' + ss.getRange(rngA1).getValues().map(function(r){return r.join(',');}).join('\n');
  Logger.log(content);...
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(content);
}
```

1. When i insert the string "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwB5QCJQICDA-0hK3ClZs_vV4NWkCrif6lRq7UBHlYN/dev?range=Sheet1!A1:C3"
   Because this code have error: value not valid row4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) is a method that needs to be applied to a sheet, rather than a spreadsheet.

Modify your code to:

```
  ...
  var content='\n' + ss.getSheetByName('INSERT NAME OF THE SHEET).getRange(rngA1).getValues()...
```